# Adding .txt as DEM using PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, addlayer

I have a bunch of .txt files which hold x and y coordinates and the elevation value.
There is no header, the file starts straight with the values.
The structure looks like: 

499100 5543200 104.19

498900 5543250 103.19

498950 5543250 102.78

499000 5543250 102.54

499050 5543250 102.34

The files can be added with drag and drop or via Layer -> add Layer -> add Rasterlayer. But there are too many files to do it by hand and I want to add them with a small python script:

```
path_to_asci = "path/to/file"
dirs = os.listdir(path_to_asci)

for file in dirs:
    demlayer = iface.addRasterLayer(file, str(file))
```

But addRasterLayer doesn´t support .txt files.

What else could I use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`QgisInterface.addRasterLayer()` *does* support .txt files. The problem is that the `file` object you are passing to the method holds only the file name and extension, whereas `addRasterLayer()` expects a valid file path. For this you can use the `os.path.join()` method to join each file string to its parent directory path.

```py
import os

path_to_asci = '/path/to/directory/containing/txt files' # Path to the folder containing your .txt files

dirs = os.listdir(path_to_asci)

for file in dirs:
    # File object will be a string e.g. 'foo.txt'
    if file.endswith('.txt'):
        # Join each file to the directory path to create a valid file path
        # e.g. '/path/to/directory/containing/txt files/foo.txt'            
        file_path = os.path.join(path_to_asci, file)
        demlayer = iface.addRasterLayer(file_path, file.split('.')[0])
        # Set whichever CRS your data is actually in...
        demlayer.setCrs(QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem('epsg:3857'))
```